# SVN file changes undetectable in Eclipse Kepler Project Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse, eclipse-kepler

Previously ran SVN in Indigo without issues. I decided to update to Kepler and have been trying to get SVN setup. Based on all of the documentation I can find I have it setup (no errors) the problem is that it is not recognizing the SVN properties of my projects and I don't see any way to get it to link.(Clicking "Team" only shows the menu item "Apply Patch"). The Preferences for SVN is totally different from Indigo so I can't match that either.. Clearly I'm missing something..

I installed the below Subclipse version
http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x

Answer (score 0):

First off, why did you install an ancient version?  Current Subclipse is 1.10.x.

The behavior you describe sounds like what you see when the project was associated with a Team Provider that is no longer installed.  I would guess that your Indigo workspace was using Subversive plugin, not Subclipse.  So Eclipse sees the project as connected to a Team Provider already but one that is not installed.  So none of the Team menus are installed.

Your options:

1) Create a new workspace and use File > Import existing projects, or just checkout projects again.

2) Uninstall Subclipse and Install Subversive

3) Install Subversive, use Team > Disconnect on all projects then uninstall Subversive.  You should then be able to use Team > Share Project to connect them to Subclipse as team provider.

If you stick with Subclipse, I would use a newer version.